# could not actually find how from_db_value works in django source code?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a some fields in my model where I am trying to apply encryption on all the fields. Each field encryption depends on the values of two other fields in that same model class. I am able to achieve the encrypted data.
But I also need those two other fields in the same class to decrypt the other field values that is returned by the function def `from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, *args)`.

I have read [the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) and source code, but I didn't see a proper explanation on the following parameters in `from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, *args)`:

1. `expression`
2. `*args`

I want to know how and where we can supply these parameters. How else we can use that function. I know the function should return the value from database converted into an appropriate python object. But I want to know what else it can do or we can do with it?

P.S: Yes, I am trying to make custom field classes. 
Inspiration: [`django-fernet-fields`](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how far you want to go down the rabbithole, but maybe this helps. As you probably already found `from_db_value` is used in the `Field` class in `django.db.models.fields.__init__.py` line 708. It's used here as a way to hook into the value conversion for models for specific databases. For example it is used to convert to native PostGreSQL array field.

If you dig a little deeper you'll find these converters are used by the `SQLCompiler` class in `django.db.models.sql.compiler.py` line 1084. Which in turn is called by `results_iter` below it.

I noticed the [how-to guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) doesn't mention using and `*args` argument in the method definition. So I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: From what transpires from the code around the spot you mentioned in SQLCompiler, it seems `expression` is used to pass some SQL expression—a `SELECT` expression it seems—that is used to get the value to be converted. But what expression is passed precisely isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. The SQLCompiler performs some magic which results in an expression but it was to complicated for me to dive that far. Just thought I'd try to help